# java serial read() is waiting indefinitely - how to break it?

Tags: java, serial-port, read-data

I have a serial device connected to my PI that I read data from it...
everything is good , but sometime the cable move or the serial device is unplug.

then the

```
line = r.readLine();
```

get stuck

I have try to overcome this problem by:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (newnputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));     
         try 
            {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line.length() == 0)
                {
                    logfile.append("problem");
                    logfile.close();
                    System.out.println("Problem");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                    break;
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                logfile.append(line);
                logfile.close();
            }
```

but it doens't do nothing (because I geuss he is still waiting for data)
not even throw an exception
how can I make him say I have a problem ? 
maybe to use a timer or something like this ? 
if no data for 5 seconds ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Is `r` a `BufferedReader` by any means?

Comment: sorry      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption in this case is right. The `readLine()` method of the `BufferedReader` has an internal `while-loop` which will retrieve all bytes from the underlying input stream and will only break if the arriving character is either `\n` or `\r`.

Think of it like:

```
while(lastChar != '\n' || lastChar != '\r')
{
     //read from stream
}
```

However once entered the method will not return. The only exceptions are the occurence of those two special characters or if the InputStream is closed (in which case `null` ist returned).

The trick is to no enter until there is something to read from the InputStream:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{

  boolean awaitInput = true;

  while(awaitInput)
  {
    if(System.in.available() != 0)
    {
      awaitInput = false;
      // read logic
    }
  }
}
```

This is only one of many possible solutions and I used System.in as an example since it is a InputStream like any other as well. But there is also a method called `BufferedReader#ready` which returns `true` if there is something to read:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

  boolean awaitInput = true;

  while(awaitInput)
  {
    if(br.ready())
    {
      awaitInput = false;
      String line = br.readLine();
      // read logic
    }
  }
}
```

At last if you want a timeout you can easily do it yourself like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
  boolean awaitInput = true;
  long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5_000;
  //                                          ^^^^^ 5_000ms = 5 sec 

  while(awaitInput && System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout)
  {
    if(br.ready())
    {
      awaitInput = false;
      String line = br.readLine();
      // read logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: great I have done what you expalin using the System.in.available - and now I think it's OK . I will continue work on it and see if I have more problem... Thanks

Comment: I have try for 1 day to run the r.ready() ,2nd option . and it's gibe me fault once every ~ 3 seconds. while whn I read the data with simple serial program (putty) - I don't get any disconnection.... so it's strange , maybe I can give the read "more" time to read?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture` to read concurrently and be able to use a timeout.

```
// wrap the readLine into a concurrent call
CompletableFuture<String> lineFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> r.readLine());
try {
    // do the call, but with a timeout
    String readLine = lineFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // do stuff with the line you read
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // plug pulled?
}
```